# Rust restart a program from another program

Tags: linux, rust

I know how to do it from inside a program:

```
Command::new("/proc/self/exe").exec();
```

Because this is prone to failure I want this structure:

1. Main program - saves to a file eg. timestamp every 30 seconds.
2. Controller program - checks the file and if the timestamp is eg. over 2 minutes ago, restarts the main program.

I don't know how to get the name of the process (can I save the process name as well as the timestamp to a file so that controller program has all info needed?).
How to ensure every thread spawned from the main one is killed before restart happens? The above works but would it work from outside analogically?

Target os will be Ubuntu 18.04 but currently I'm just experimenting on Linux Mint.

Comment: Sounds like a systemd work. Do you have to write this in rust?

Comment: I would rather have the parent and child talk via a pipe than use a file...

Comment: I've set it up on systemd, how do I send the WatchDog state to systemd to restart? Docs are not very verbose.. https://docs.rs/systemd/latest/systemd/daemon/constant.STATE_WATCHDOG.html

Comment: @tommy1213 Take a look at systemd-notify.